# Recursive definition of a sequence with shifted base

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, recursion

The following is taken from *Foundations of Modern Analysis* (Dieudonné) p.22:

> Suppose $x:\mathbf{N}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ is a bijection. We define
> a subsequence $p:\mathbf{N}\rightarrow\mathbf{N}$ of integers by
> induction in the following way: $p(0)=0$ and $p(1)$ is the smallest
> value of $n$ such that $x_0<x_n$. Suppose $p(n)$ has been defined for
> $n\leq 2m-1$, and that $x_{p(2m-2)}<x_{p(2m-1)}$; then the set
> $]x_{p(2m-2)},x_{p(2m-1)}[$ is infinite and we define $p(2m)$ to be
> the smallest integer $k>p(2m-1)$ such that
> $x_{p(2m-2)}<x_k<x_{p(2m-1)}$; then we define $p(2m+1)$ as the
> smallest integer $k>p(2m)$ such that $x_{p(2m)}<x_k<x_{p(2m-1)}$. It
> is immediate that the sequence $(p(n))_{n\in\mathbf{N}}$ is strictly
> increasing, hence $p(n)\geq n$ for all $n\in\mathbf{N}.$

I am having difficulty understanding the recursion process with which $p$ is defined. Normally, given $p(n)$ has been defined, we define $p(n+1)$. But here the author assumes that $p(n)$ has been defined for $n\leq 2m-1$ and that $x_{p(2m-2)}<x_{p(2m-1)}$, for some $m\in\mathbf{N}_{\geq 2}$, before defining $p(2m)$ and $p(2m+1)$. What is the justification here? (e.g. why can he assume "$x_{p(2m-2)}<x_{p(2m-1)}$"?)

Can someone please translate this definition of $p$ into a standard recursive definition?

**Edit:**

Essentially, the process defines the following for $m\in\mathbf{N}_{\geq2}$:

1. $p(2m):=\min\{k\in\mathbf{N}\ |\ p(2m-1)<k\land x_{p(2m-2)}<x_k<x_{p(2m-1)}\}$;
2. $p(2m+1):=\min\{k\in\mathbf{N}\ |\ p(2m)<k\land x_{p(2m)}<x_k<x_{p(2m-1)}\}$.

So I guess one would have to show that the following set are nonempty for $m\in\mathbf{N}_{\geq2}$, correct?

**Edit 2:**

I would really appreciate if someone could put this recursion in the form prescribed by the Recursion Theorem in set theory:

> Given a set $X$, an element $a\in X$ and a function $f:X\rightarrow
>  X$, there exists a function $F:\mathbf{N}\rightarrow X$ such that
> $F(0)=a$ and $F(n+1)=f(F(n))$.

Answer (score 1):

It **is** a standard recursive definition; it just happens in this case to be necessary to define two items at each stage. We want to construct $p$ so that

$$p(0)<p(2)<p(4)<\ldots<p(5)<p(3)<p(1)\;,\tag{1}$$

so that

$$\big(p(0),p(1)\big)\supsetneqq\big(p(2),p(3)\big)\subsetneqq\big(p(4),p(5)\big)\supsetneqq\ldots\supsetneqq\big(p(2n),p(2n+1)\big)\supsetneqq\ldots\;.$$

We do this be constructing two values of $p$ at each stage. At stage $m$ we assume that we’ve constructed $p(0),p(1),\ldots,p(2m-1)$ so that

$$p(0)<p(2)<\ldots<p(2m-2)<p(2m-1)<\ldots p(3)<p(1)\;,\tag{2}$$

i.e., so that $(1)$ is true as far as we’ve gone at that point. Then $\big(p(2m-2),p(2m-1)\big)$ is a non-empty open interval, so we can choose $p(2m)$ inside it and have $$p(2m-2)<p(2m)<p(2m-1)\;.$$ Then we similarly define $p(2m+1)\in\big(p(2m),p(2m-1)\big)$, so that

$$p(2m)<p(2m+1)<p(2m-1)\;,$$

and we can now replace our induction hypothesis $(2)$ with

$$p(0)<p(2)<\ldots<p(2m)<p(2m+1)<\ldots p(3)<p(1)\;.$$

However, the last sentence in the block quote in the question is false: the sequence $\langle p(n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is **not** strictly increasing. The sequence $\langle p(2n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is strictly increasing, and the sequence $\langle p(2n+1):n\in Bbb N\rangle$ is strictly **decreasing**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to justify this process by the recursion theorem in set theory?: i.e. in this form: "Given a set $X$, an element $a\in X$ and a function $f:X\rightarrow X$, there exists a unique function $F:\mathbf{N}\rightarrow X$ such that $F(0)=a$ and $F(n+1)=f(F(n))$"? What would be the $f$ in our case? Obviously $X=\mathbf{N}$ in our case.

Comment: @alf262: Yes, but not with $X=\Bbb N$: take $X$ to be the set of all pairs $\langle x_k,x_\ell\rangle$ with $k<\ell$ and $x_k<x_\ell$, and take $a=\langle x_0,x_n\rangle$, where $n$ is minimal such that $x_0<x_n$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Would you mind saying (briefly) what $f$ is supposed to be here? It takes a pair $(x_k,x_l)$ with $k<l$ and $x_k<x_l$ and returns another pair with similar properties, but what how should the output pair be extracted from the input pair?

Comment: @alf262: Exactly as $p(2m)$ and $p(2m+1)$ are extracted from $p(2m-2)$ and $p(2m-1)$ in the block quote.

Comment: Sorry but your choice of $X$ can't work because $F=p$ is supposed to be a sequence with codomain $\mathbf{N}$ and not $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}$ (which your choice for $X$ is a subset of). Also, $p$ is strictly increasing: $p(0)<p(1)$ by definiton; $p(2)$ is defined as the least $k>p(1)$ such that ..., $p(3)$ as the least $k>p(2)$ such that ..., and so on: i.e. $p(0)<p(1)<p(2)<p(3)<...$

Comment: @alf262: No, $p$ is **not** strictly increasing as defined in your block quote; the final quoted sentence is simply (and obviously) wrong. As for $X$, I assumed that you would realize that the $F$ produced by that (very limited) version of the recursion theorem would then require a little processing in order to produce $p$. And even if $F$ **were** $p$, its codomain would not be $\Bbb N$: it would be $\Bbb R$. (And I did not previously notice that you were claiming that $x$ was a bijection: that’s clearly impossible.)

Comment: You are right about that: this is part of a larger proof that is used to show that $x$ cannot be a bijection (it's the proof of the non-denumerability of $\mathbf{R}$). I will keep my upvote but I will remove the green check.